# Build never terminate with jenkins

Tags: jenkins, automated-tests

I have problems with creating a job in jenkins. At the "Build" step I select Build "execute windows batch command", where I want to start a browser such as opera, google chrome portable or firefox portable, the command never terminates.[View screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VizxL.jpg)

For IE, firefox and chrome I do not encounter any problems
If someone has a solution. thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you expect? You have launched an executable that shows a form, albeit in a session that can never have a console session attached.

Jenkins, by design, will sit there until the executable terminates - which generally happens when the form is closed by a user interacting with it. Since there is no GUI, this process can only ever terminate if someone kills it with Task Manager.

What are you actually trying to achieve? There's almost certainly a reasonable way to do it.

Comment: Thank for your answer. In fact I launch a web page which after some actions kill the browser automatically. With IE chrome and firefox i haven't any problem but with FirefoxPortable Google chrome portable and opera, yes.

Comment: Well, Jenkins won't move on to the next build step until after the browser process terminates, simple as that, by design. 

I suggest instead of starting the browser, start an executable of your own design that, in turn, starts the browser, starts whatever tests you want, then terminates the browser, outputs test results to stdout or a file, then terminates itself (with a zero error code for SUCCESS and a non-zero code for a FAIL).

Comment: But the browser process is not started (not even visible in the task manager). When i test the command on my command prompt the test is successful while with jenkins, no...

Comment: Have you selected `Show processes from all users` in Task Manager? Do you still not see the process? Does the user you are using to run Jenkins have permission to run the browser executable?

Comment: Thanks, I didn't check this.Now I see the process and I didn't check "allow the service to interact with desktop" in jenkins' property. My problem is solved. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: No worries, glad you're sorted.